# In WP7 how to force the ListPicker to show in full mode (or send a tap)?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listpicker

I need to programmatically force a (WP7 toolkit) ListPicker to show its list in full mode.
How can I do that (or how to send the tap gesture or click to indirectly do the same)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the `ExpansionMode` of the `ListPicker` to your desired style. Via XAML

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="MyListPicker"
                    ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"
                    >
  ....
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Or in code;

```
MyListPicker.ExpansionMode = ExpansionMode.FullScreenOnly
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Combine this with Open() method in the 7.1 toolkit